# How to position a rectangle based on size of a window?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to draw a rectangle and place it on the screen depending
on the size of the window / screen.

I've got this but it doesn't work:

```
with self.canvas:
    Color: xyz
    Rectangle(pos=(Window.size[0]-50,Window.size[1]-50),size=(50,50))
```

This didn't have any effect either:

```
with self.canvas:
    Color: xyz
    Rectangle(pos=(Window.height-50,Window.width-50),size=(50,50))
```

**Runnable example:**

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import *

Window.size = (375, 812)

class Temporary(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Temporary, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(255/255.0, 99/255.0, 71/255.0)
            Rectangle(pos=(0,0),size=(50,50))

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Temporary()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: So what is the failure? Also `Color: xyz` doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: @inclement The `Color` attribute xyz is just a filler attribute. Not relevant to the question. I'm not getting any errors on my placing efforts. The rectangle just sits on 0, 0 by default. I don't want to use fixed coordinates because that would be a mess on different screen sizes.

Comment: @inclement I've also considered to reference other widget's positions but they all use `pos_hint` so I can't use it for Rectangle. Rectangle doesn't follow `pos_hint`.

Comment: Post a minimal runnable example

Comment: @inclement I added minimal executable code.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work as I intended:

```
class Temporary(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Temporary, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(255/255.0, 99/255.0, 71/255.0)
            Rectangle(pos=(Window.size[0] / 2,Window.size[1] / 2),size=(50,50))
```

Nothing else worked. The above will do the trick.