# Kivy text input autocompleting Wikipedia addresses

Tags: kivy

I would like to implement text input, that is able to autocomplete
Wikipedia addresses.
For example, what you start typing `dog`, you have `do` so far
and it will suggest:

`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do`

`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump`

`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog`

`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominican_Republic`

...
as in Wikipedia search engine

And would be fine, if it could solve somehow `disambiguation pages` as well, but it's not necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of your application has to be broken into two parts, the first is you GUI and the second is the logic that checks for wikipedia pages.

The GUI part consists of a `TextInput`, a binding that will call the function that checks for wikipedia pages and finally a way to display these results. Since you haven't specified how to display these results, I will just assume that they are to be displayed in a `Label`.

The GUI might look something like this:

```
# main.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from wiki_recommendations import WikiSearcher


class SearchBar(TextInput):
    
    articles = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(text=self.on_text)
        self.bind(articles=self.on_articles)

    def on_text(self, *args):
        WikiSearcher().get_search_results(self.text, self)
        
    def on_articles(self, *args):
        label = self.parent.ids['results']
        label.text = ''  # Reset the text
        for article in self.articles:
            label.text = label.text + '\n' + article


kv = """
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: self.width * 0.1
    spacing: self.height * 0.1
    
    SearchBar
        size_hint: 1, 0.2
        multiline: False
        font_size: self.height*0.8
        
    Label:
        id: results
        size_hint: 1, 0.8
"""


class SearchApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SearchApp().run()
```

Our `SearchBar` object has two bindings. The first calls the `on_text` callback when the user inputs text. This initialises a search, passing the text the user submitted as an argument. The second binding is to a `ListProperty` that fires the `on_articles` function when the `articles` property receives data from `WikiSearcher()`. This function updates the `text` property of the `Label`.

The logic that checks the wikipedia pages should look something like this:

```
# wiki_recommendations.py

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import threading


def thread(function):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        t = threading.Thread(target=function, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, daemon=True)
        t.start()

        return t
    return wrap


class WikiSearcher:
    url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search'

    @thread
    def get_search_results(self, text: str, root):
        """
        This function uses the BeautifulSoup library and the requests library to get the top Wikipedia articls
        :param text: The text to be searched.
        :param root: The object that calls this function - useful for returning a result.
        :return:
        """
        # Web scraping happens here
        top_articles = []  # The results of your web scraping
        root.articles = top_articles
```

I won't code the web scraping in this answer, as to do so would take a load of work! I have however, noticed that there exists a special wikipedia search page (see url property). When searching "*hello*" into the bar the web address returned is:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=hello&title=Special%3ASearch&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&advancedSearch-current=%7B%7D&ns0=1

The key here is the **search=hello** bit of the URL. Perhaps you can manipulate the URL so that this snippet changes in accordance with the `text` argument passed to the `get_search_results()` function. Something like:

```
url = f"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search={text}&title=Special%3ASearch&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&advancedSearch-current=%7B%7D&ns0=1"
```

but I'll leave that with you to figure out, as this is beyond the remit of Kivy.

You absolutely should use a thread when calling this function, otherwise it will cause the GUI to stutter, resulting in a really poor looking user interface.

Finally, when this function has done its thing, the last thing it should do is update the `SearchBar.articles` attribute. This is where the `root` argument comes in, which provides a convenient way to access this class across files. Updating `root.articles` in-turn calls `on_articles` which displays these articles in a Label.

Comment: I tried to run it with `top_articles = ["hello"]` but I can't see the label.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I realised that I made a slight spelling error in my answer. `root.top_articles = top_articles` should instead be `root.articles = top_articles`

Comment: I have fixed the error in the answer and have successfully tested it on my computer

Comment: OK, I don't need the parsing code, but the following functionality is important: When i click the text "hello" it should appear in the TextInput as in Wikipedia page when you're searching. I'm not sure if label is most convenient for this. Isn't it possible to use some dropdown menu, or something like this?

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.dropdown.html This might be of use. You could use the `on_select` event to update the `TextInput.text` property

Comment: I tried it with the dropdown, but there is probably something [wrong](https://pastebin.com/x0pRKk6K) yet. Could you please look at it?

Comment: And isn't it better to use this [API](https://stackabuse.com/getting-started-with-pythons-wikipedia-api/) than scraping? What are the pros and cons? And what is the best way to search in all languages?

Comment: Definitely use the API, the API will be much faster and more reliable. However, still use the structure posted in my answer (using threads) to prevent the GUI from being interrupted. Just instead of web scraping submit a GET request to the API.

Comment: And could you look please what's [wrong](https://pastebin.com/x0pRKk6K) on this?

Comment: Yes am on it now. I think using a DropDown menu is actually going to be more trouble than its worth. I will post a different solution.

Comment: I accept this and ask new question with the problems I'm encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here are some of the improvements to the solution that I have already posted, but since I have made quite a few changes I thought I would post another answer. Here is the final code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import webbrowser
from wiki_recommendations import WikiSearcher


class SearchBar(TextInput):
    articles = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(text=self.on_text)
        self.bind(articles=self.on_articles)

    def on_text(self, *args):
        WikiSearcher().get_search_results(self.text, self)

    def on_articles(self, *args):
        self.parent.ids['recommendations'].update_recommendations(self.articles)


class SearchItem(ButtonBehavior, Label):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.url = ''

    def on_release(self):
        webbrowser.open(self.url)


class Recommendations(BoxLayout):

    def update_recommendations(self, recommendations: list):
        for (search_item, recommendation) in zip(self.children, recommendations):
            search_item.text = recommendation
            search_item.url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + recommendation


kv = """
<SearchItem>:
    canvas.before:
        Color: 
            rgba: [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1] if self.state == 'normal' else [30/255, 139/255, 195/255, 1]
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
            
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    
BoxLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Color: 
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: self.width * 0.1
    spacing: self.height * 0.1

    SearchBar:
        size_hint: 1, 0.2
        multiline: False
        font_size: self.height*0.8

    Recommendations:
        id: recommendations
        orientation: 'vertical'
        SearchItem
        SearchItem
        SearchItem
        SearchItem
        SearchItem
"""


class SearchApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SearchApp().run()
```

I have created a custom `SearchItem` object which is essentially a minimalist button, but on pressing it you are redirected to the appropriate wikipedia page. To be honest you could have just used a `Button` object, but from my personal experience I prefer the freedoms and flexibility of creating a `Label` endowed with the `ButtonBehavior` behaviour.

Alongside this is a wiki_reccomendation.py file:

```
import wikipedia
import threading


def thread(function):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        t = threading.Thread(target=function, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, daemon=True)
        t.start()

        return t
    return wrap


class WikiSearcher:
    url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search'

    @thread
    def get_search_results(self, text: str, root):
        """
        Gets the top Wikipedia articles
        :param text: The text to be searched.
        :param root: The object that calls this function - useful for returning a result.
        :return:
        """
        root.articles = wikipedia.search(text)
```

This remains mostly unchanged. Here is what the app looks like now:

[image: screenshot of app]

As the user types in the search bar the `WikiSearcher` object is instantiated and the `get_search_results()` is called. This updates the `articles` property of the `SearchBar` which in turn updates the children of `Recommendations` (a BoxLayout). These children are essentially just Buttons which direct the user to the recommended page when they are pressed.

I will leave you with making it look pretty - if that is important to you - but I think that is it. Note this only displays the top 5 recommended articles. You can add and remove recommendations (to have more or less than 5) using the `clear_widgets()` and `add_widgets()` methods, but simply updating the ones on the screen is much faster.

Comment: Thank you for such a large solution, though I like the previous solution more, because there is a possibility or could be possibility to scroll between recommendations, so I'll let it open for some time yet, if you (or I) could make the previous solution viable. I really appreciate your work and you'll be certainly awarded.

Comment: I really appreciate UI in this solution.

Comment: No worries. If it's scrolling you wish then I suggest looking into https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html . I tend to use `ScrollView` a lot more than I use `DropDown`. The document even shows how it can be used with a `BoxLayout`

Comment: Thank you, I actually switched to `FloatLayout` because I needed spinner with language code on the left.

Comment: Here, I can't figure out why the ordering is not the same, as in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) search (e.g. the word "python")

Comment: I already know it, in Wikipedia there are `suggestions` in autocompletion.

Comment: Please, how can I change the position of the searched items (i'd like it to be more to the top) and the size of the searchitem (to be more in the height). I already changed the UI, because I needed spinner, button etc. and everything is in the popup Window. But I'm struggling with the position and size. I haven't studied canvases yet, so it's new for me. Thank you

Comment: Normally you would use the `pos` attribute and the `size` attribute to change the position and size of the widgets. There are of course other ways of changing the position and size of a widget, for instance by modifying the `pos_hint` and `size_hint` attributes. However, I can't really without more information. Could you post a new question (with code) and link it here in the comments?

Comment: I'd like to change the position `Rectangle` based on `Window` size as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64267387/how-to-position-a-rectangle-based-on-size-of-a-window) ` e.g. `pos=(Window.size[0] / 2,Window.size[1] / 2)`, but I can't use `Window` in `kv`

Comment: Here is the [new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67115473/move-search-items-more-to-the-top) question. Thank you.