# Move search items more to the top

Tags: kivy

I have the following code snippet displaying a `popup` Window.

```
class SearchBar(TextInput):
    articles = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(text=self.on_text)
        self.bind(articles=self.on_articles)

    def on_text(self, *args):
        WikiSearcher().get_search_results(self.text, self)

    def on_articles(self, *args):

        self.parent.parent.children[0].update_recommendations(self.articles)

class SearchItem(ButtonBehavior, Label):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.url = ''

    def on_release(self):
        print (self.url)


class Recommendations(BoxLayout):

    def update_recommendations(self, recommendations: list):
        for (search_item, recommendation) in zip(reversed(self.children), recommendations):
            search_item.text = recommendation
            try:
                search_item.url = wikipedia.page(recommendation).url
            except:
                search_item.url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + recommendation.replace(" ", "_")

Builder.load_string('''
<SearchItem>:
    font_size: self.height * 0.4
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1] if self.state == 'normal' else [30/255, 139/255, 195/255, 1]
        Rectangle:
            #pos: self.pos
            #size: self.size[0], self.size[1]
            size: root.size[0], root.size[1]
            pos: self.pos[0], self.pos[1]
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Line:
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height

    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
<Urlpup>:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: 'Enter URL or keywords'

    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: self.width * 0.1
        spacing: self.height * 0.1

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Spinner:
                id: spinner
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.4
                pos_hint: { 'top' : 1 }
                text: 'en'
                values: 'en', 'fr', 'de', 'it'

            SearchBar:
                id: url_input
                size_hint: 1, 0.4
                pos_hint: { 'center_x' : 0.5, 'top' : 1 }
                multiline: False
                font_size: self.height*0.8

            Button:
                text: 'OK'
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.4
                pos_hint: { 'top' : 1 }
                on_press: root.dismiss()
                on_release: app.create_new_article(url_input.text)

        Recommendations:
            id: recommendations
            orientation: 'vertical'
            SearchItem
            SearchItem
            SearchItem
            SearchItem
''')

class Urlpup(Popup):
    pass
```

Here is a picture of the `popup` Window[image]

You can see that the `SearchItems` are not tightly below the `SearchBar`, where I'm struggling to position it. Can you fix it? On the picture there are 4 `SearchItems` but I plan to have 10 `Searchitems` so it should work for 10 `SearchItems` or be flexible when I decide to change the number of `SearchItems`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BoxLayout` tries to distribute its available space equally among its children, unless you tell it otherwise. So, your top level `BoxLayout` in the `Urlpup` class evenly divides its space between the `BoxLayout` containing the `TextInput` and the `Recommendations` widget. You can reduce the space between those two widgets by limiting the space given to the horizontal `BoxLayout`. You can do that by specifying a height for that `BoxLayout`, like this:

```
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Spinner:
            id: spinner
            size_hint: 0.5, 1
            pos_hint: { 'top' : 1 }
            text: 'en'
            values: 'en', 'fr', 'de', 'it'

        SearchBar:
            id: url_input
            size_hint: 1, 1
            pos_hint: { 'center_x' : 0.5, 'top' : 1 }
            multiline: False
            font_size: self.height*0.8

        Button:
            text: 'OK'
            size_hint: 0.5, 1
            pos_hint: { 'top' : 1 }
            on_press: root.dismiss()
            on_release: app.create_new_article(url_input.text)
```

Note that the children of this `BoxLayout` all have a `size_hint_y` of `1.0`, so they will all be the height that is specified for their container.

The `Recommendations` widget gets the remaining vertical space (minus the `spacing`). You can move the `Recommendations` even closer by reducing the `spacing`.

Comment: Thank you. And why the height is 50? Could this be relative to the screen size? The app should work on tablets as well (larger screens).

Comment: And the text is little below the searchbar. It looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/CKsuHEp)

Comment: I just picked 50 at random. Since that `BoxLayout` just holds text related widgets, it just needs to be large enough to hold that text.

Comment: You can set `font_size: sp(30)` for the `TextInput`. And perhaps `height: sp(50)` for the `BoxLyout`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and it seems to work. If it won't I will let here know.